# How to fix wordpress error in wp-admin created by jetpack

Tags: php, wordpress, fatal-error, jetpack

I recently uncounted an error on my wordpress site which prevents me from accessing the admin panel. However the main site is not affected by it.

> Warning:
>   require_once(/var/sites/s/stlukesnorwich.org.uk/public_html/wp- 
>   content/plugins/jetpack/class.jetpack.php): failed to open stream: No
>   such  file or directory in
>   /var/sites/s/stlukesnorwich.org.uk/public_html/wp- 
>   content/plugins/jetpack/jetpack.php on line 68
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 
>   '/var/sites/s/stlukesnorwich.org.uk/public_html/wp- 
>   content/plugins/jetpack/class.jetpack.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/local/php- 
>   5.6.37-flock/lib/php') in /var/sites/s/stlukesnorwich.org.uk/public_html/wp- 
>   content/plugins/jetpack/jetpack.php on line 68

At the moment I have had to disable the jetpack plugin via ftp. Once disabled the error disappear and I can access the admin panel again.

It would be great if anyone could offer some pointers as to what could be causing this error as I could do with having the jetpack plugin activated.

I had a look at the line causing the error

```
require_once( JETPACK__PLUGIN_DIR . 'class.jetpack.php'               );
```

Comment: does the file in this path exist `/var/sites/s/stlukesnorwich.org.uk/public_html/wp- 
content/plugins/jetpack/class.jetpack.php`?

Comment: No it looks like it doesn't

Comment: download it from here `https://github.com/Automattic/jetpack/blob/master/class.jetpack.php`and put it in that path...

Comment: Great thanks the error has gone away however I think it's missing other files but I've found them and I'll add them. Thank you very much